# Unhelpful android crash stack trace… no way to know what is happening

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

I am suffering an android crash and have no idea about it. Could anyone give a hand here? Don't know what more to do. The stack trace is below:

```
#19393 UnityMain
SIGSEGV(SEGV_MAPERR)

1 #00 pc cac13760 <unknown>
2 #01 pc abe74c74 <unknown>
3 java:
4 com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
5 com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
6 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
7 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
8 com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
```

P.D: I'm using unity 5.6.1p2 and the project was created with this. Android 6.0, level 23.

Comment: But what is this?

Comment: Crash log usually contain the reason. Copy and post of all of them as it is then post your Unity and Android version